# delphi 2010 IDE 'error insight' error

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2010

when I open concrete projects the error insight mark with red lines incorrect areas of the screen. Also when I compile It, error messages are shown, but the line number displayed in the message window points to a wrong line in the code window. When I double click over a error message the ide goes to another line. how do i correct this problem?

Regards,

Francis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Francis--

It is very likely that your files have some issues with their line endings.

Has the file ever been opened in another editor besides Delphi?

You can check this way:  Copy all of the code onto the clipboard, paste it into Notepad, copy it all out of notepad, and then paste it back into the editor.  That should clean up all the line endings.  See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Work fine with any editor except notepad. The problem appear after copying and pasting from an old winhelp file.

Thanks

Comment: I usually find it easier to close the file in the IDE's editor window, open it with an external text editor (not Notepad - I've been told that won't fix mismatched CR/LF pairs) like Notepad++ or WordPad, make a nonsense change like adding and then removing a blank line, and then saving the file. Opening it again in the IDE works fine afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Turn off error insight. First thing I do after installing. Then fix the line endings as noted earlier.

Comment: Not sure if this is necessary for D2010, but D2006 is a LOT more stable with error insight turned off.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I like error insight and this is the first time I get this error. Delphi 2010 is really really stable.

Comment: So do I (sometimes), but it makes D2006 behave badly - huge memory leaks if code is not compilable.

Comment: Turn off error insight. First thing I do after installing. (me too)